# Description of Eurus in Ovid's Metamorphoses

Tags: poetry, ovidius, mythology

Here's a quote from Ovid's Metamorphoses 1.61-2, where he talks about Eurus, the east wind:

> Eurus ad Auroram Nabataeaque regna recessit
>
> Persidaque et radiis iuga subdita matutinis

I've translated it to myself very roughly as

> Eurus blew towards Dawn and the kingdoms of Nabatae and Persia, and towards the mountains submissive to the morning lights.

As far as I can tell, this translation is essentially correct. However, Eurus being the *east wind* should mean it blows *from* the east, and this excerpt seems to be saying the opposite, since it states that Eurus is moving eastward to Nabate and Persia.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This passage (*Met*. 1.61-2) is about the creation of the world, and the winds are taking up their allotted quarters. Eurus isn't blowing towards the East, he's taking up his station there to become the East Wind.

(Btw *subdita* here isn't "submissive to", but simply "placed under".)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!